# how to use incgraph to obtain a landscape cover?

Tags: graphics, titles

I tried this

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,x11names,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}  
\usepackage{incgraph,mwe}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\begin{document}
\incgraph[paper=document][width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a.eps}
jei
\end{document}
```

but the image is not as I want. Any parts are out, and an parts are in white, as you can 
see

-edited after Werner´s comment

[image]

How to correct this?

Comment: Perhaps a `angle=-90` or `angle=90` could help in the second optional argument of `\incgraph`, it least for `\includegraphics`

Comment: the image is well oriented, the problem is that a part it´s out of the paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is specific to a compilation sequence via LaTeX, since using XeLaTeX or pdfLaTeX compiles without problem. Here is a work-around, using [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) to insert the picture in the foreground of the first page only:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}  
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}
\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \raisebox{-\height}{%
      \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}%
    }%
  }%
}

\null\clearpage

Some content

\end{document}
```